# How to create a GWT page?

Tags: html, gwt, uibinder

I have to make a website with different Java-Tasks and informations. The user can join the homepage and can click to different pages. On the Java page he can do some tasks. The website is completely done with HTML. Now i need GWT for the tasks.(multiple choice etc.) This page is easy to make, when i only have this page. But how can i put all these things together. I mean: a homepage and different pages with only html and links and a page which is also linked to all other pages for navigation and is done with gwt for the different tasks. Do i need GWT for all the other pages or only for the task-page? On the other pages there is only text.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need GWT for all the pages, but you can use it.

You can create a GWT project with a Module for the GWT page you want and a static HTML for each one of the HTML pages.

Alternatively, you can build a web application that loads the content of each page dynamically in the same element (e.g. in `<div id="content"></div>`), based a URL token (e.g. < url >**#somepage**) triggered by your menu items. You can get the token value in GWT with `com.google.gwt.user.client.History.getToken()`.

Web applications such as Gmail work like that. For your use case, with many static pages (pure HTML), it might seem to be an overkill. But if you are using GWT anyway, I would do it like that. In the long term you don't have to update the menu in each HTML page, as you have a single widget for that. You get scalability and a better project organization.